# Cracks on second-story cement slab

Tags: concrete, cement

I just purchased a 50-year-old condo. I pulled up the carpet and found the second floor to be a concrete slab. There are thin cracks in areas and a small pit in one area.  What are my options for resolving/minimizing cracking.

1. Rhino Crack Locks
2. Tear it all out and start over, my least desirable option
3. Just fill in the cracks and leave it.

There are no cracks in the walls etc., it's not a foundation issue.

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeating Answers from previous question but now revised.  Answer to your revised question.
I would go with option (3) fill in the cracks

If repairs/sealing of the cracks is to be done, I would go with two types of products, liquid/self leveling for the thinner-fine cracks and a heavier product for the larger cracks.  For the liquid, look at products similar to [Dap 37584 product](https://www.lowes.com/pd/DAP-32-oz-Gray-Concrete-Patch/3024887) and for the larger cracks, [Dap Ready-Mixed Patch](https://www.lowes.com/pd/DAP-32-oz-Gray-Concrete-Patch/1085955).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a cosmetic issue if it's 50 years old and not having foundation issues. In which case "Option C: fill it and leave it" seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Your comment is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a topping slab from your second image. Its purpose isn't structural at all but to dampen noise for the levels below when you walk around. Wood buildings can be loud and this is a common a solution.

My advice would be to cover it up with a carpet or any type of flooring. This was the original intent for the building and the most effective solution. The width of the crack is very minimal and it's likely that it will never get wider than it already has over it's 50 year life.

Comment: Thank very much. My intent is to lay carpet with a high quality padding.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Much appreciated.

Comment: @TAC the generally accepted way of saying "thank you" around here is to give the answer an up vote. Since this one doesn't have any votes (at the moment), I presume you've overlooked that option. It's also considered appropriate to wait about 48 hours, then click the check mark to "accept" an answer as the one that helped you the _most_ (since there are often more than one "correct" and "helpful" answers). It doesn't look like you've taken the [tour] or looked through the [help] yet, you'll find those most helpful.